# Server returned nothing (no headers, no data) when attaching socket.io

Tags: node.js, http, ecmascript-6, socket.io

I'm using node.js 16 with es6 support enabled and express js,

```
    import express from 'express'
    import http from 'http'
    
    const app = express()
    app.get('/health', (_req, res, _) => {
    console.log('health check')
    res.sendStatus(200)
    },
    const server = http.createServer(app)
    server.listen(
         8000, '127.0.0.1'
        )
```

> here everything works fine, sending get request on
> localhost:8000/health return 200

**But when I attach socket.io to my HTTP server**
I get the following error

> Server returned nothing (no headers, no data)

I added socket.io like so

```
import { Server } from 'socket.io'
onst io = new Server()
io.attach(server)
```

**Hints everything was working fine with nodejs 14**
that's how my package.json lunch scipt look like

```
"main": "src/index.js",
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --es-module-specifier-resolution=node src/index.js",
},
```

> I get no error when starting the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Issue was with Insomnia ,
when I tried curl it worked

Comment: Having the same issue with Insomnia. What is your solution?

Comment: i switched to Postman